execute vertex on AIでファイルが読み込めない
【前提】
vertex AI workbenchでのnotebookをexecute vertex on AIで動かしたい。その中で特定のサービスアカウントでcredentialsの認証をする必要がある。これには、jsonファイルを使用したい。
【課題】
この時、手動でnotebookを動かすとコードは動くが、execute vertex on AIで動かすと動かない。あるはずの絶対パスにファイルが見つからない。これをどう対処すればいいですか
